# c-source is not a good relative path

Tags: hackage

I try to upload a package to hackage and get the brief message

```
c-sources: C/libqhull_r.c' is not good relative path: same directory segment: ..
```

I cannot find (with google) any hint what is meant and what I should change (I am not the author of the code, but have permission of the author to upload to hackage).

The cabal file contains

```
    include-dirs:        C
    C-sources:           C/libqhull_r.c
                       , C/geom_r.c
                       , C/geom2_r.c
```

and builds with cabal build.

Comment: You could try `./C/libqhill_r.c`

Comment: I do not understand fully, but it worked. Thank you! -- It would be nice if the message was a bit less cryptic.

Comment: lets try something else, please to get a more satisfyimg answer. What happens if you don't pretend C/ at all. you already have C in the include-dirs. so maybe it complains because of that.

Comment: if i leave out the `C/` cabal coplains `Warning: File listed in qhull.cabal file does not exist: libqhull_r.c`. My question is, what is not relative at the path `C/xxx.hs` and what is hackage expecting. Where is it explained in the hackage documentation?

Comment: I found something:
https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/7426

Comment: @HEllRZA   Thank you - this answers the question and identifies a shortcomming on hackage. Once understood, one can live with it.